# Generic method that accept only part of classes

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

Suppose I have following class structure:

```
class Base {}
class A extends Base {}
class B extends Base {}
class C extends Base {}
```

I want to write method, that accepts instances of *A* and *B* but not instances of *C*.
Can I achieve it in Java?

I know this is not good inheritance situation (*A* and *B* should have common parent different from *C*), but I am only curious is in Java way to handle situation like this.

**EDIT:**
!!!
I know that better inheritance will resolve problem. I am only curious, if Java have some standard mechanism to solve problem like that.
!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the answer to your questions is "No, java does not have a standard way of dealing with such a problem". And if you have this problem then you can look at other answers here, like fixing the inheritance or using the clever technique [given by MrSmith42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13990845/866022).

Comment: @MichałHerman correct ? 17 - 1 ... blimey, this is like being at work.

Comment: @NimChimpsky don't worry, there's badges for this sort of thing. :)

Comment: Yes, I for me this answer is correct, because I asked IF Java have some build mechanism to deal this kind of problems. Not HOW to deal with this type of problems by myself, because this I already know.

Answer (score 43):

Use an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) and have only `A` and `B` implement it.

Answer (score 13):

Can you use an interface? e.g.

```
class Base {}
interface MyGenericInterface {}
class A extends Base implements MyGenericInterface {}
class B extends Base implements MyGenericInterface {}
class C extends Base {}
```

That way, the method can accept implementations of MyGenericInterface, and since A and B implement the interface but C does not, it will accept instances of A and B but not C, as required.

Answer (score 8):

If something should accept `A`, `B` but not `C` then you should reconsider why `C` is inheriting from `Base` in the first place. You could add an extra layer of inheritance:

```
   ---Base---
   |        |
--Sub--     C
|     |
A     B
```

Then you could allow your method to only accept objects of type `Sub`. `Sub` doesn't even have to do anything, and they're all, technically, also `Base`.

A quicker solution would be a dirty `if( arg.instanceof(C) )` though...

Answer (score 8):

You can handle it at runtime using exception:

```
void genericMethod(Base arg_in)
{
    if(arg_in instanceof C)
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("C class not accepted."); 
    }

    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A type-hierarchy should not be changed only because you want to have such a method.
But the case that you want to have such a method may indicate you should think over your 
type-hierarchy.

But if you are sure your types are well designed, what about this approach:

```
    public class T {

        public void doSomething(final A a) {
            doSomthing(a);
        }

        public void doSomething(final B b) {
            doSomthing(b);
        }

        private void doSomthing(final Base b) {

            // Here is the implementation

        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know what you were intending with the `final` keyword there, but it won't prevent a widening conversion from occurring at the call site.  Since every instance of `C` is an instance of `B`, it will always be possible to pass instances of `C` into your `doSomething()` method.

Comment: Why do you think  "C is an instance of B" ? A,B,C all only extend Base

Comment: 'final' has nothing to do wthe the functionality. Just a codeing convention I am used to.

Comment: Hmmm... on revisiting this, it appears I misread the question. My apologies.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instanceof` to check if an object is of a certain type.

Better idea would be better inheritance structure, of course.

Comment: To be clear: In Java, `instanceof` works for subclasses.  That is, `C c = new C(); c instanceof B` will return true.  If you want to exclude `C`, you need to check for it explicitly.  (Adding a comment because at first glance this answer wasn't clear to me.)

Answer (score 2):

Generics is for type safety. Period. Not to "allow" or "disallow" arbitrary things. There is no type-safety reason to allow A and B and not C.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below snippet**

```
public <T extends Base> void setAuditorDetails(T model) 
{
         if(!(T instanceof C)){

              // Your Business logic

         }
}
```